# codeigniter SELECT query function

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter and trying to access data from mysql database

here is my model class code

```
function model_data($a){
$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT* FROM mytable3");
return $query->result();    
}

function model_data_cat(){
$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT* FROM mytable1");
return $query->result();    
}
```

Actually i am calling two functions in my controller. one is model_data and the other is model_data_cat. but i get error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in "

However when i try this piece of code it works perfectly.

```
function model_data($a){
$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->get('mytable3');    
return $query->result();    
}

function model_data_cat(){
$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->get('mytable3');    
return $query->result();    
}
```

Can anybody helps me...
Thanks.

Comment: can u put complete error code + controller code ?

Comment: The error is not in this code. Sounds like you missed a `;` somewhere. Please show your *exact* code.

Comment: Check http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html - this isn't solution to your problem but maybe you can find useful :)

Comment: Why not load the database library in the constructor for the model rather than as part of every function? Also, if you do want all the results, the `get()` method is probably the best way to go, if you need to be more specific with the results you want then @uzsolt's link would be a great way to build the query.

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the code you posted (although `SELECT*` is a little awkward compared to `SELECT *`). You truncated the error message in your post, which should have the exact file name and line that has the error (probably in your controller). I suggest you post the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the library in autoloads in config folder

The query can be generated in different ways like:

```
$res = $this->db->get('table_name')->result();
return $res;
```

will be accessible with `foreach` loop like

foreach($res as $key){
$value = $res->result();

}

Answer (score 0):

As you've said that changing the code to the CodeIgniter inbuilt get query helper works, the only thing I see in that code that *might* cause an issue is that there is no space between the `SELECT` and the `*`.

This *shouldn't* cause an issue, but as there's nothing else to go on here, it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected $end almost always means you missed an ending brace, parenthesis, quote, etc. somewhere in the code and it's not in that spot.

Also, since you said the alternative segment works, I've also sometimes run into problems when I copy / paste code.  Try making sure there's nothing on the lines there and rewrite the code segment.